# GDB not finding symbol table

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb

I cannot determine the reason that gdb is either not finding the proper debugging symbols or they are not being generated by my makefile.  I have added and removed various flags such as -g, -ggdb, and -O0 in as many combinations as I can think of.  Any help would be appreciated!

Makefile:

```
FLAGS =-std=c++11 -ggdb -g -O0 -Wall -Werror
CC = g++
OBJS = main.o LSorter.o LNode.o

default: exec

exec: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o exec $(OBJS) 

main: main.cpp LSorter.h LNode.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp -o main.o

LSorter: LSorter.cpp LSorter.h LNode.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c LSorter.cpp -o LSorter.o

LNode: LNode.cpp  LNode.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c LNode.cpp -o LNode.o

clean:
    rm exec $(OBJS)
```

Console Output:

[image: gdb console output]

Comment: What about if you compile your program, and start gdb with `gdb ./a.out` then `start`?

Comment: I actually did this, I just cut it off to not show my user name.  Still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OBJS = main.o LSorter.o LNode.o

exec: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o exec $(OBJS)
```

This specifies that the `exec` target depends on `main.o`, `LSorter.o`, and `LNode.o` targets.

The `make` command then proceeds to search your Makefile for any rules to build `main.o`, `Lsorter.o`, and `LNode.o`.

Unfortunately, `make` fails miserably in this noble quest. Your `Makefile` fails to define any rules for targets named `main.o`, `Lsorter.o`, and `LNode.o`. `make` then defaults to using its implicit rules, that build `.o` files from `.cpp` files that it finds with the same name. The default built-in rules, that are built into `make`, know absolutely nothing about your `FLAGS` variables, and if you paid close attention to the commands that `make` was executing when compiling your `cpp` file you would've noticed that your `cpp` files were not compiled with your `FLAGS`, and therefore did not have any debugging data compiled in.

Your makefile does appear to have rules defined for targets `main`, `LSorter` and `LNode`, which use `FLAGS` to specify the `-g` option.

Unfortunately, those are not the targets that `make` was instructed to search for, as I explained.

This is an obvious oversight. Change your build rules to specify the correct dependency targets, then `make clean` and recompile.